# What is an ideal time to update modified content field of table and show it to Users?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, setinterval

I am working in an application where I have to show application users that contents of this page was modified like :

```
1 min ago
5 min ago
2 days ago
something...
```

Then what should be ideal time interval to fire an ajax call to get last modified date for contents from db and to show to users?

JavaScript has setInterval() where we can set function (to fire ajax call and get last modified date) and time interval (based on which a function will be called to fire ajax call).

Why I am asking because firing ajax call within very few seconds can be considered as an overhead to application.

Please suggest me on this.
Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***
I am appreciating your comment and checked plugin. But whenever any changes are made to DB table there is one parent table which has modifiedDate field which is updated on every changes and that I have to show to users.

Comment: No need to send an Ajax call. Send the actual update time with the document and have Javascript calculate and update the 'time ago'

Comment: @MikeW, I am appreciating your comment and checked plugin. But whenever any changes are made to DB table there is one parent table which has modifiedDate field which is updated on every changes and that I have to show to users.

Comment: *to comment further on your updated question:* There is no **correct** interval, you would have to use something like **comet** or **socket.io** to have updates sent to client *as they change*

Comment: @Jakub, I heard about it while I was checking how SO periodically updates everything and still it's a light weight site. But thanks for your great help. I just wanted to confirm about firing ajax call to minimize the overall overload of site. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to waste calls to a DB to get an interval. No single interval would be correct and it would be just pointless updates.

Just use a simple JavaScript plugin like **[timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)**.

It makes it easy by just printing the *original date/time* and the plugin does the rest auto updating your user as they view your page, so this date:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Turns into this for the user:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">5 years ago</abbr>
```

Comment: I am appreciating your answer and checked plugin. But whenever any changes are made to DB table there is one parent table which has modifiedDate field which is updated on every changes and that I have to show to users.

Comment: well you didn't outline that in your question originally. I would still say use this approach *or* go more complex and depending on how many values you get, just do 1 single interval check for **ALL** records on your page (return JSON with changes and update in as needed for what gets changed). This plugin will still make things *pretty*

Answer (score 1):

No need to send ajax requests repeatedly. Just get the date / time with the main contents, and place it in a hidden field in HTML. Then using javascript/jquery, get that date / time and process it, and display it on the appropriate place(s).

Answer (score 0):

unless you are familiar with websockets i would make the call every minute OR just refresh the page every minute so you can fetch the last modified date accurately.

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 60 * 1000);
```